# How to make Jquery only in on component and not in another page or component in angular 4 by using jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

i placed below code in my Home page(first component inside ngOnInit() function in angular 4 ) and it is working fine but if i goto next webpage through home page this below jquery script is affecting header so how avoid it (like jquery code only works in home not in another page especially window scrolling)

```
    $(window).scroll(function ()
    {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 310) {
    $(".header").addClass('nav-background-color');
    }
    else
    {
    $(".header").removeClass('nav-background-color');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in ngOnDestroy() method in angular 4

```
$(window).off('scroll')
```

then the scrolling only works in one page where you initialization your code in that page, not in other pages